# 800A03EA javascript syntax JScript compilaton error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, compilation, jscript

A very annoying compilation problem is happening to my computer regarding JScript and node, I already tried several instructions provided by the internet however the problem seems to persist.

CD>PROJECT
`npm init` ok
`npm install -g` and locally ok
`npm start` > problem with start: script > `app.js` or `node app.js` ok

If it runs I receive the Windows host server error #800A03EA syntax/compilation issue.

[image]

However, if I run the code 
`npx http-server`, I can do my PWA projects with no issue.

I have already tried several 'fix' tools, repair, registry verification, but none of them seems to solve the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JScript (interpreted by windows script host, WSH) is not the same as JavaScript (interpreted by node*).

The error mentioned sounds as if the *JScript* interpreter of the Windows Script Host was trying to execute a *JavaScript* file intended for node.

Make sure you run your code with node (`node app.js`) and not with WSH. The default file association in windows for *.JS is WSH so doubleclicking or just running `app.js` will run WSH.

Also make sure your `start` command in `package.json` is actually set to `node app.js`, I get the feeling it is set to just `app.js`.

```
... 
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js"
} 
...
```

Then, `npm start` should work.

**: Of course node is not the only interpreter for Javascript, but it's the one relevant here.*

Comment: I also tried this, same error, the only way I can put my project on a local host is trough `npx http-server` command. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show the full console input and output and contents of your package.json file. It doesn't make sense that you get this error with node, it must come from WSH.

Comment: (also you need npm install without the -g switch, but that would the next problem after this one)

Comment: Done, take a look below

Comment: Now i see the mistake, thanks for the support ! I wish you all the best.

Comment: I was really confused.

Answer (score 0):

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Dev\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle np@1.0.0~prestart: np@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle np@1.0.0~start: np@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle np@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle np@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Fetch api\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle np@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Fetch api
10 silly lifecycle np@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node scripts.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle np@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle np@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: np@1.0.0 start: `node scripts.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid np@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Fetch api
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Dev\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error np@1.0.0 start: `node scripts.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the np@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

```js
PS C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Fetch api> npm start

> np@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Fetch api
> node scripts.js

C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Fetch api\scripts.js:1
var button = document.querySelector('.button')
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Fetch api\scripts.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! np@1.0.0 start: `node scripts.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the np@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-23T18_39_34_693Z-debug.log
```

```js
PACKAGE JSON

{
  "name": "np",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^6.14.5",
    "prpl-server": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/mendesbayout/Fetch-api-simple-forecast.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mendesbayout/Fetch-api-simple-forecast/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mendesbayout/Fetch-api-simple-forecast#readme",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: But now it's a totally different error... It seems you are running a javascript file that's intended for the browser with node instead. So maybe `npx http-server` is the right way for you after all.

Comment: ... But why is it now scripts.js? Didn't you say it is app.js?

Comment: Also it's a totally different folder now... Even a different user (Dev instead of Coops)

Comment: I switched names trying to make it work, but I am keeping the one with app.js, this one works fine on $npx http-server. However I would love to understand why my computer does this strange behavior. He is only able to run a node server with plenty of packages installed.

Comment: I think you have some big confusion here, if it works with `npx http-server` then you are just serving static files, meant for the browser. With `node something.js` you would try _executing_ the file with node on the server side which of course doesn't make sense if it is intended for the browser. So I think you got something mixed up there. And again it seems you are now talking about two entirely different programs, `n-4-8-geocoding` and `Fetch-api-simple-forecast`, which work in different ways...

Comment: The `n-4-8-geocoding` is from [here](https://github.com/borkaehw/nodejs/tree/master/n-4-8-geocoding) and should work with `node app.js` just fine (after `npm install` _without_ `-g`). The `Fetch-api-simple-forecast` from [here](https://github.com/mendesbayout/Fetch-api-simple-forecast) is actually a single-page-app for the browser without any server side component, it has a useless `package.json` file with an incorrect `start` script and an unnecessary `git` module dependency - so this one just needs `npx http-server` (or any other static file server, not even necessarily node)

Comment: So the reason you get this error on `npm start` is because the package `Fetch-api-simple-forecast`'s `package.json` file is a red herring, the author probably didn't know how to use it. So it ends up doing a totally wrong thing (calling `app.js` on Windows with the default file association, which is the Windows Script Host) when you do `npm start`.

Comment: But the package.json was initiated on NPM INIT and I added the Start script. The javascript is OK as its running on other setups, it seems that this issue is happening only in my laptop.

Comment: fetch ('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputValue.value+'&appid=0f91ec65ce9099b9b43a35a9f89f6f26')
.then(response => response.json()) .. I am GETiing data similar to geocoding but using fetch.

I will try another approach like starting server through JS, then node it. Thanks a lot for the attention bud

Comment: Guys thanks for the help, now I understand my BIG mistake. Thanks for the support, I really really appreciate it ! ... it was a big big confusion i'm ashamed !

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the beginning of the js file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

It will tell your system which interpreter use to run the file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).