# 800A03EA JScript compilaton error with Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Hello I am trying to run a react app with Electron. I followed the instructions online and added the following to my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },
```

This caused the error: 800A03EA JScript compilaton error. Which seems to have a solution on this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967777/800a03ea-javascript-syntax-jscript-compilaton-error) which suggests running the code with the node environment. So I change it like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "node electron ."
  },
```

However, I started getting another error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'whenReady' of undefined. And [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933477/typeerror-cannot-read-property-whenready-of-undefined) says the issue is running it with "node." So now I am confused, if I remove that I get one error but if i add it I get another. I am a bit confused on what to do. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

This is my electron.js file, which the error complains about:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const localServerApp = express();
const PORT = 8088;
const startLocalServer = (done) => {
  localServerApp.use(express.json({ limit: "100mb" }));
  localServerApp.use(cors());
  localServerApp.use(express.static('./build/'));
  localServerApp.listen(PORT, async () => {
    console.log("Server Started on PORT ", PORT);
    done();
  });
};

function createWindow() {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:" + PORT);
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  startLocalServer(createWindow);

  app.on("activate", function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't need to add "node". Then, the second error means you have something wrong in your code. It's not possible to help you find the problem if you share only your scripts. Are you sure you installed electron?

Comment: Hello. I added my electron.js file, which is what the error complains about. I hava electron installed through npm, version electron@29.1.4